# Inconsistent result of SVN diff command

Tags: svn, diff

**Problem**: the `svn diff` command seems to be inconsistent when executing on a whole repository, compared with the execution on a single file.

**An example**: consider the **r542208** commit of the Apache Tomcat source code.

`svn log -v -r r542208 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/`

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r542208 | fhanik | 2007-05-28 13:39:15 +0200 (H, 28 máj. 2007) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CometEventImpl.java
   M /tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java
   M /tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java
   M /tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11NioProcessor.java
   M /tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11NioProtocol.java

Implement setTimeout using an Action instead of an attribute

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now let's consider source file `/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java`. Executing a repository wide diff provides some result.

```
svn diff -r r542207:r542208 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat
```

The `Request.java` related part of the result is the following:

```
===================================================================
--- trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java       (revision 542207)
+++ trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java       (revision 542208)
@@ -2259,6 +2259,9 @@

     // ------------------------------------------------------ Protected Methods

+    protected void action(ActionCode actionCode, Object param) {
+        coyoteRequest.action(actionCode,param);
+    }

     protected Session doGetSession(boolean create) {
```

(There are other parts of the result as well.)

But if we execute the diff command on that file only, the result will be empty.

```
svn diff -r r542207:r542208 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java
```

I would expect the same result as quoted above.

It is also strange that the above indicated 3 new lines are missing when listing that version of the source file, but the line above and below exist.

**The question**: what could cause this strange behavior? Is there any setting which maps the basis of the SVN to other directory (a branch for example)? Or maybe a later directory rename could cause this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, you fell victim to the "Peg Revision Fallacy". Some time in its history, the file `Request.java` was replaced by another file of the same name. Therefore, you need to make sure that you also specific the correct *peg revision* when querying the repository, which is done by appending `@revision` to the path in question. Thus, the following command will yield nothing (as you reported)

```
svn diff -r r542207:r542208 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java
```

but if you add the correct peg revision, you will see the expected changes:

```
svn diff -r r542207:r542208 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java@542207
```

The revision in which the the original `Request.java` was removed is `573772`, in which the whole repository tree was deleted and replaced by another one. More information can be found at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html.

Comment: Great, this solved the problem! Many thanks! (I can't vote up because of the low number of reputation.)